# The best practice for passing formatted string to methods

Tags: c#, coding-standards

Though it might be trivial for someone, I find it a little inconvenient when someone formats the string while passing it as a parameter to a method. For e.g.

```
AddMessage( string.Format("{0} (" + Constants.Message1 + ")",
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(document.FileName)),           
    string.Format("{0}" + FileExtensionPdf,
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(document.FileName)));
```

I have taken a simple example here, but it could become a little messy sometimes. I prefer to not do this and instead format my string before I pass them to the method. For me, this reduces readability.

I would like to know if there is a standard practice which goes against the above style. Since I am doing a code review, I am not sure if I should put it as a comment.

Comment: Never do or advocate something "because others do it". That is really all that "standard" or "practice" means. Do it because it provides a benefit over doing it differently. Formatting messages with substitutions like `printf` does greatly increases readability, so that is the reason you should be giving.

Comment: In the example code you are using both formatting and concatenation, which looks a bit strange. That's the first thing I would comment in a code review.

Comment: C# 6 added string interpolation which greatly helps readability in string formatting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx

Comment: There will always be devs who sacrifice readability for brevity. Some (mainly from non-C/C++ backgrounds) despise the ternary operator for example.

Comment: @17of26 - The link says service is unavailable.

Comment: @RobbieDee - I agree. But I personally prefer a code which is neat and more readable if brevity compromises readability.

Comment: @ShaktiPrakashSingh link works fine for me, just google 'C# string interpolation'

Comment: @17of26 Thanks, found it. This is something I didn't know about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would probably format your example code something like this:

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(document.FileName);
AddMessage(
    foo: string.Format("{0} ({1})", fileName, Constants.Message1),
    bar: string.Format("{0}{1}", fileName, FileExtensionPdf));
```

I think it's fine to format your input directly in the call as long as you do it in a readable way. Here I also use named arguments since it's two string arguments and I want to communicate clearly and avoid the stupid mistake of swapping those arguments.

Using a temporary varible for the file name with no extension is both an optimization of code and readability.

Comment: +1 Much better. The redundant code is removed, the author gets to keep their inline formatting and there are named arguments.

Comment: This looks much better as well as concise. You expanded it just enough make it cleaner and more readable.

Answer (score 4):

I would simplify Torbjørn's answer with string interpolation:

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(document.FileName);
AddMessage($"{fileName} ({Constants.Message1})", $"{fileName}{FileExtensionPdf}");
```

Comment: I haven't started using C# 6 yet, but this is obviously very nice :)

Comment: Me neither but certainly a bauble to look forward to...

Comment: it is neat, but i do feel that we lose something when we move away from the explicit use of the variables

Comment: The explicit variables are still there!

Answer (score 1):

I agree expanding it out makes it more readable and maybe easier to debug. not sure I would raise it as a problem though.

```
const string msgFormat1 = "{0} ({1})";
const string msgFormat2 = "{0}.{1}";

string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(document.FileName);

string msg1 = String.Format(
    msgFormat1,
    Constants.Message1, 
    fileName
);

string msg2  = string.Format(
    msgFormat2, 
    fileName,
    FileExtensionPdf,
);

AddMessage(msg1, msg2);
```

edit : stole filename optimization from other answer

Comment: Creating `msgFormat1` and `msgFormat2` moves the formats further away from where they are used, making it harder to read now (in my opinion).

Comment: I guess it depends somewhat on the rest of the code on whether one design is demonstrably better than another. ie are the formats used elsewhere/loaded in from config etc

Comment: Yes, I agree. I will always inline the formats if I can though (if they are unique to this call to Format, if they are not dynamically loaded, and so on..)

Comment: I agree with @Torbjørn - not sure the **const** statements add anything here, but still much better than the original...

Comment: @RobbieDee - I agree this is much better than the original one. But I think I would go with Torbjørn's solution. In fact, I probably would have thought of this if I would have done it myself, but when I look at it, the arguments of AddMessage call somewhat do not provide as to what is the information that is being passed. Though, it makes the code much cleaner.

Comment: I suppose if I were trying to justify the bestness of my answer I would say that the key difference for me, is not so much the const formats, but not calling functions in the parameters of the AddMessage call

Comment: This creates more code to mentally parse and I think it's less readable than the original.